# Triple (Almost) Gaps - Schezo's Edition

Tags: grid-deduction

[image: Triple (Almost) Gaps - Schezo's Edition]

> *Today (Mar 16) is Schezo's birthday! Happy birthday my little creeper boi~ <3*

**Clarifications**:

- $C$ may or may not be equal to $1$.
- The set actually tells you that at least one of $\{C,M,N,P,R,T\}$ is $1$.
- The number for $WWWWBBB$ is $0$.

Comment: can column 4 be, for instance, wwwwbbb (white=w, black=b)?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Oh, no, it's not allowed.

Comment: Why is there an arrow from C to 1 and from T to question mark?

Comment: @darksky it's just denoting {C,M,N,P,R,T} should be replaced by {1,?,?,?,?,?} in some order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91125/discussion-between-athin-and-darksky).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer would be:

> [image]

The letters are:

> C = 3,
>  
>  R = 2,
>  
>  P = 0,
>  
>  T = 1,
>  
>  N = 2,
>  
>  M = 2

The boundary of the grid reads:

> *I am not a creeper*

The set formed is:

> {C, M, N, P, R, T} = {3, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1}

Comment: Yep, that's it! Great job :D